# Suggesting 2 diferents design

Tags: webpack

I would like to suggest 2 diferents design for my web `app`.

What and How should I have to define it in webpack so it can generate 2 bundles files?

One will be call fromn `index.html` other one from `index_alt.html`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcPzKMZzyqc).
I solved my problem

In order to have multiple outputs for each entry I have to do the following:

```
entry: {
    vue: './src/main.js',
    vue_alt: './src/main_alt.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'../Server', config.path),
    publicPath: '/resources/',
    filename: '[name].app.js' // name will have the value of each properties of the entry (vue, vue_alt)
  },
```